# How to filter data before get it out from the database?

Tags: android

I use `cursor` get data from database,But there are some unnecessary data in it.I want to know how to show the data exactly I want to show,not all I get from the database,I can't judge this when query the database ,only can handle it after I get the data out,I hope the app can filter the data automatic after get data .

**NEW EDIT**

I have consider that put all data in a list ,use the list as a data source.(I use listView in app),but there already has a `cursoradapter` and some methods like `bindView`.if I add a new adapter ,the code will be too complex and miscellaneous.

Comment: Why you are not using the WHERE-clausel? Like "Select * From TableXY Where _id < 5;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like...

```
private static final Uri SMS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] {"date", "address", "body", "type"};
private static final String WHERE = "type = 2";
private static final String ORDER = "date DESC";

// ...
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(SMS_URI, COLUMNS, WHERE + " AND date > " +
            timeLastChecked, null, ORDER);
```

This lets you query `content://sms` and return only the `COLUMNS` you want, that fit your `WHERE` criteria, at the `ORDER` you decribed. The `null` is used to replace the `?` you used in the query (like Java's `PreparedStatement`).

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html